# How to get all file paths from a Github repository

Tags: c#, git, github

I'm using the GitHub Developer API v2. Currently need to retrieve all the file paths from a repository. Has anyone experience in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a starting point, you can check what the output of a ls-tree looks like.
But:

- some parsing of that output will be in order for you to get the exact result you want.
- it doesn't seem to be recursive!

Getting in tree in [GitHub Api V2 is described here](http://develop.github.com/p/object.html).
Only the [GitHub Api V3](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/) mentions a `?recursive=1` option.

> tree/show/:user/:repo/:tree_sha

You can see an example in [this article](http://gitorious.org/github-me/pages/GithubAPI-ObjectAPI):

> To get a listing of the root tree for the facebox project from our commit listing, we can call this:

```
$ curl http://github.com/api/v2/yaml/tree/show/defunkt/facebox/f7a5de2e224ec94182a3c2c081f4e7f4df70da4
---   
tree:   
- name: .gitignore  
  sha: e43b0f988953ae3a84b00331d0ccf5f7d51cb3cf  
  mode: "100644"  
  type: blob  
- name: README.txt  
  sha: d4fc2d5e810d9b4bc1ce67702603080e3086a4ed  
  mode: "100644"  
  type: blob  
- name: b.png  
  sha: f184e6269b343014f58694093b55558dd5dde193  
  mode: "100644"  
  type: blob  
- name: bl.png  
  sha: f6271859d51654b6fb2719df5fe192c8398ecefc  
  mode: "100644"  
  type: blob
```

Comment: But how could I get the files are in the sub folders? lets say I know that sub folders name and I want to retrieve files that it contains.

Comment: @CoffeeCode: when thatrequest returns an object of type 'tree', then you restart your query, adding that tree to the path (ie adding the tree name at the end of the url).